# Adding a WCF Service (<> WCF Service Reference) gives "Specified Cast is Invalid"

Tags: wcf, exception, service, casting

When adding a second WCF service to an existing WCF project, or adding a first WCF service to a project gives me a dialog box "Specified Cast Is Invalid".  WCF files are added to the project except interface file. Web.Config isn't updated neither.

I think the problem started after updating VS.NET 2008 to VS.NET 2008 SP1.

Comment: Can you provide some detail? Clearly, this doesn't happen to everyone, so your details will be critical to solving your problem.

Comment: I just started getting this error trying to create a new web application project in vs.net 2008 sp1. Except I've had sp1 running for a while. Did you find a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

You can always reinstall SP1 if you are uncertain about the installation. A successfully install SP1 should not cause this problem.

When we have had problems adding WCF references there have generally been on of the following problems:

- Data contracts incorrectly specified, missing a tag [Datamember], [DataContract]...
- Is your Interface marked as public?
- If you are referencing a DLL with types from both the client and the server, is everything serializable and public. Are you using the same version of the dll on both sides?
- Is your contract very large? You may need to increase the buffer sizes to get the information to build the proxy.